# Search and replace all lines in a multiline string

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a string with a large list with items named as follows:

```
str = "f05cmdi-test1-name1
f06dmdi-test2-name2";
```

So the first 4 characters are random characters. And I would like to have an output like this:

```
'mdi-test1-name1',
'mdi-test2-name2',
```

As you can see the first characters from the string needs to be replaced with a ' and every line needs to end with ',

How can I change the above string into the string below? I've tried for ours with 'strstr' and 'str_replace' but I can't get it working. It would save me a lot of time if I got it work.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Have you taken interest in regular expressions yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job:

```
$input = "f05cmdi-test1-name1
f05cmdi-test2-name2";

$result = preg_replace("/.{4}(\S+)/", "'$1',", $input);
echo $result;
```

Where `\S` stands for a NON space character.

Comment: This works great! The only thing I needed to add was `mdi` before `$s`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT : I deleted the above since the following method is better and more reliable and can be used for any possible combination of four characters.

So what do I do if there are a million different possibillites as starting characters ?

In your specific example I see that the only space is in between the full strings (full string = `"f05cmdi-test1-name1"` )

So:

```
str = "f05cmdi-test1-name1 f06dmdi-test2-name2";
$result_array = [];
// Split at the spaces
$result = explode(" ", $str);
foreach($result as $item) {
    // If four random chars take string after the first four random chars 
    $item = substr($item, 5); 
    $result_array = array_push($result_arrray, $item);
}
```

Resulting in:

```
$result_array = [
    "mdi-test1-name1",
    "mdi-test2-name2",
    "....."
];
```

IF you would like a single string in the style of :

`"'mdi-test1-name1','mdi-test2-name2','...'"`

Then you can simply do the following:

```
$result_final = "'" . implode("','" , $result_array) . "'";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rafael, but I found out that there are also lines that starts with `f09cmdi` or `f11dmdi`, so not all starts with `f05c`. For example it could be `$str = "f11dmdi-test1-name1
f09cmdi-test2-name2";`

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is doable in a rather simple regex pattern

```
<?php

$str = "f05cmdi-test1-name1
f05cmdi-test2-name2";

$str = preg_replace("~[a-z0-9]{1,4}mdi-test([0-9]+-[a-z0-9]+)~", "'mdi-test\\1',", $str);
echo $str;
```

Alter to your more specific needs

Comment: Thanks, this works great, but I found out that there are also lines that starts with `f09cmdi` or `f11dmdi`. So for example it could be `$str = "f11dmdi-test1-name1
f09cmdi-test2-name2";`

Comment: Works great, thanks. Is it also possible to use his when the `test` name also changes? So if for example the list contains `$str = "f05cmdi-abc-def
f05cmdi-ghi-klm";` ?

Comment: No, it looks for test. At this point you're going to want to look at regex a bit more deeply yourself so that you can in fact figure out how to modify the pattern to fix your needs. Without having your full list, I can't write regex to match the test cases I don't know.

Comment: I fully understand. My list starts with `f002mdi-access-point
f003mdi-access-point-network
f004mdi-account
f005mdi-account-alert
f006mdi-account-box
f007mdi-account-box-outline` Based on this list is it possible?